# is_singular won't call my functions?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, archives, single

Hi i'm using this code to call for a different stylesheet for a single post type but the problem is, It won't call the stylesheet.

It's in header.php, i also tried placing it in single.php

```
<?php
if ( ! is_home() ) {

if ( is_single() == 'pretty-little-liars' )  {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tv-cafe.com/wp-content/themes/tvcafe/posttypecss/style-pll.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
}
}
?>
```

can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is_single()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a string. Additionally, you can test for a specific post with `is_single()` function by putting the post slug into the function call:

```
if ( is_single( 'your-post-slug' ) )
{
    # do something
}
```

If you want to test for the proper post type use:

```
if ( is_singular() and 'your-post-type' === get_post_type() )
```

or just:

```
if ( is_singular( 'your-post-type' ) )
```

### Edit

And for your specific question, you should wrap that script into a callback, hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts`. In `functions.php`:

```
function wpse78368_enqueue_custom_stylesheet() {
    if ( is_singular( 'pretty-little-liars' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 
            'style-pll',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/posttypecss/style-pll.css' 
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse78368_enqueue_custom_stylesheet' );
```

Note: Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` because `wp_enqueue_styles` doesn't exist as a `do_action()`.

Comment: Het @Toscho thanks, but doesn't `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse78368_enqueue_custom_stylesheet' );` go before `function wpse78368_enqueue_custom_stylesheet() {`

Comment: @MihadAiko The order doesn’t matter.

Comment: i didn't place the enueing in the header i placed it in the functions.php if i use is_single( 'pretty-little-liars' ) it won't work i have tried that. Are you saying that if i call it in functions.php i don't need to call it in the header, because it doesn't work by just calling it in the functions or just in the header.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid creating a single-{custom post type}.php for each custom post type.

Comment: @toshco Thank you that works great lol :) Thank you for so much of your help. I'm learning a bit more :)