# is_single query calling the wrong stylesheets?

Tags: custom-post-types, query, single, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is_singular won’t call my functions?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78368/is-singular-wont-call-my-functions)

So I am trying to call different style sheets for each of my post types single page.

Here is the code I am using in my header file.

```
<?php
if ( ! is_home() ) {

if ( is_single() == 'pretty-little-liars' )  {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tv-cafe.com/wp-content/themes/tvcafe/posttypecss/style-pll.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
}
if ( is_single() == 'revenge' )  {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tv-cafe.com/wp-content/themes/tvcafe/posttypecss/style-revenge.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
}
if ( is_single() == 'once-upon-a-time' )  {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tv-cafe.com/wp-content/themes/tvcafe/posttypecss/style-onceuponatime.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
}
}
?>
```

and I also learned that I had to add this code in my functions.php in order for it to work properly

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse78368_enqueue_custom_stylesheet' );
function wpse78368_enqueue_custom_stylesheet() {
if ( is_single( 'pretty-little-liars' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-pll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/posttypecss/style-pll.css' );
}
 if ( is_single( 'revenge' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-revenge', get_template_directory_uri() . '/posttypecss/style-revenge.css' );
}
if ( is_single( 'once-upon-a-time' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-onceuponatime', get_template_directory_uri() . '/posttypecss/style-onceuponatime.css' );
}
}
```

But the problem is that, the code is calling the last stylesheet of the code. It is calling the "Once Upon A Time" stylesheet for each custom post type singular page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is still the same error like in your last question: use `is_single( 'pretty-little-liars' )`, **NOT** `is_single() == 'pretty-little-liars'`. And enqueuing the stylesheets is enough. Don not print them manually into the header file.

Comment: @toscho i didn't place the enueing in the header i placed it in the functions.php if i use `is_single( 'pretty-little-liars' )` it won't work i have tried that. Are you saying that if i call it in functions.php i don't need to call it in the header, because it doesn't work by just calling it in the functions or just in the header.

Comment: And you are sure `'pretty-little-liars'` is the slug of that post?

Comment: @toscho "pretty-little-liars" is the custom post type i have added 2 more custom post type "revenge" and "once-upon-a-time" Each post type has a different stylesheet for the archive, but the single post under each post type doesn't. Now using what you and chip suggested seems not be really working, It's calling the style sheet from once upon a time, for every single post under every CPT, and yes thats the correct slug.

Comment: Okay, I made an update to my previous answer to show the difference.